# Kivy buttons not working as intended

Tags: python, kivy

I've started making my first kivy app a few days ago and everything went fine up till one point.

I have a Label which has GridLayout inside and 256 buttons (`PaletteColorButton`) that are supposed to represent palette. I created an `on_touch_down` method for this class and try to click on any of the buttons, they all execute what's inside of `on_touch_down`.

Here's the most important part of my code:

```
class PaletteLabel(ToolBarLabel):
    def make_palette(self, layout):
        for i in range(0, 256):
            palette_color_button = PaletteColorButton()
            with palette_color_button.canvas:
                Color(i/255, i/255, i/255, 1)
            layout.add_widget(palette_color_button)


class PaletteColorButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            print(self.pos)


class BamEditor(App):
    Config.set('kivy', 'window_icon', r'.\static\program_icon\BamEditor-icon.png')
    def build(self):
        main_label = MainLabel()
        main_label.ids['palettelabel'].make_palette(main_label.ids['palettelayout'])
        return main_label
```

And here's the data from .kv file:

```
<PaletteLabel>:
    height: 160
    width: 640


<PaletteColorButton>:
    size:(20,20)
    canvas.after:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x + 1 , self.y + 1
            size: self.width - 2, self.height - 2
<MainLabel>:
    PaletteLabel:
        id: palettelabel
        pos: (self.parent.x + 120, self.parent.y + 20)

        GridLayout:
            id: palettelayout
            cols: 32
            rows: 8

            pos: self.parent.x , self.parent.y
            size: self.parent.width, self.parent.height
```

I want to have only the clicked button's `pos` printed, but instead I get positions of all 256 buttons, does anyone know how to achieve that? Ofc, I can use `on_press` instead and it works, but I'd like my buttons to have different behavior when tapped once and different when tapped twice. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the kivy programming guide:

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> […]
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-events

When you don't want to manage the touch in this button, (so when the collision test fails), you should let the event dispatch to the rest of the widget tree

```
    return super(WidgetClass, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Comment: Ok, this is super interesting! This may explain why when I clic on 1 button other button get activeted too